# How to get hooks of any WordPress themes & Plugins

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, hook

I want to know, how can i get hooks of any WordPress themes or plugins. Is there any way to get it?

Comment: Usually there is a documentation for that, I think it's a good starting point. If not, ask for the dev of your theme/plugin

Comment: This plugin will give you best info about what is happening - https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ . Keep in mind to not use it on live website since its performance heavy.